# Array with key in swift

Tags: uitableview, swift

i am using this code to get text from array with key

This code in view did load

```
    if let rs = db.executeQuery("select * from myTable", withArgumentsInArray: nil) {

        while rs.next() {

            let id = rs.stringForColumn("id")
            let text1 = rs.stringForColumn("text")

            dataArray.addObjectsFromArray(NSArray(objects:NSDictionary(object:NSArray(objects: id, text1), forKey:NSArray(objects: "id", "texti"))))



        }

    } else {
        println("executeQuery failed: \(db.lastErrorMessage())")
    }
```

...

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = dataArray[indexPath.row].objectForKey("texti") as? String

    return cell
}
```

The cell label text is null, why?

---

```
    println("dataArray: \(dataArray)")

dataArray: (
        {
                (
            id,
            texti
        ) =         (
            1,
            John
        );
    },
        {
                (
            id,
            texti
        ) =         (
            2,
            Mark
        );
    },
        {
                (
            id,
            texti
        ) =         (
            3,
            Marry
        );
    }
)
```

Is there a problem in this?
I am using same code in objective-c and its working probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `self.tableView.reloadData()` after you retrieve the `dataArray`. Change the `dataArray.addObjects` line to

`dataArray.addObject(["id":id,"texti" : text1])`

```
if let rs = db.executeQuery("select * from myTable",    withArgumentsInArray: nil) {

    while rs.next() {

        let id = rs.stringForColumn("id")
        let text1 = rs.stringForColumn("text")

        dataArray.addObject(["id":id,"texti" : text1]) // Added Line
    }
    self.tableview.reloadData() //Added Line

} else {
    println("executeQuery failed: \(db.lastErrorMessage())")
}
```

Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if let txt =  dataArray[indexPath.row].objectForKey("texti") as? String
{
    cell.textLabel?.text = txt
}
```

Comment: i do it, same issue....this code right or not:     cell.textLabel?.text = dataArray[indexPath.row].objectForKey("texti") as? String